# Why does the ButtonClick event on DropDown control not fired in VSTO Ribbon?

Tags: c#, excel, vsto

For example, I add a DropDown Control and its ButtonClick event handler method:

```
 private void dropDown1_ButtonClick(object sender, RibbonControlEventArgs e)
 {
     MessageBox.Show("I am clicked.");     
 }
```

but, when I click DropDown control, it doesn.t show the message, which mean the event not fired. How to explain this?

Comment: Are you sure a drop down has a button click event? Are you looking for the DropDown event or SelectedIndexChanged?

Comment: Did you choose any item on the list?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The event is fired when a button is clicked on the list. So, you need to fill the list of `Buttons` like shown on the screenshot:

[image: drop down ribbon buttons]

Comment: Thanks. I think the MSDN doesn't clarify it ...